# Does an Amazon RDS endpoint change in the event of instance failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, endpoint

I would like to know if an Amazon RDS endpoint ever changes when a DB instance crashes and is brought back up. I want to setup 2 EC2 instances (additional EC2 instances may be spun up depending on traffic) hosting a Django app pointing to an RDS MySQL DB. Since the DB host name (i.e. endpoint) is provided in the settings.py file, do I need to worry that I will need to change it in case the DBInstance fails?

If the endpoint does change, can you make any recommendations on how to automate pushing the new endpoint to the settings.py file? I want to minimize any downtime of the app in case of EC2 or RDS instance failures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon RDS instance endpoints will not change. You should however, ensure you have your RDS in multiple availability zones. See here for some caveats and recommendation with RDS availablility -- http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#12